# Using two SELECT FROM syntaxes inside INSERT INTO problem

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named `ps_manufacturer_lang` with 4 columns named `id_manufacturer` and `id_lang` and `description` and `short_description`.

1. `id_manufacturer` should be values from `SELECT id_manufacturer FROM ps_manufacturer`.
2. `id_lang` should be `1`.
3. `description` should be values from `SELECT description FROM prestashop_old.ps_category_lang WHERE id_lang='1' AND id_category IN (
   SELECT id_category FROM prestashop_old.ps_category WHERE id_parent='241')`
4. `short_description` should be `NULL`.

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO ps_manufacturer_lang (id_manufacturer, id_lang, description, short_description)
SELECT
    id_manufacturer
FROM ps_manufacturer
    1,
SELECT
    description
FROM prestashop_old.ps_category_lang 
WHERE 
    id_lang='1' 
    AND id_category IN (
        SELECT id_category FROM prestashop_old.ps_category WHERE id_parent='241'
    )
    NULL
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1,
SELECT
    description
FROM prestashop_old.ps_category_lang
WHERE
    ' at line 5
```

It seems it's not possible to use two `SELECT FROM` syntax inside one `INSERT INTO`.

Any help on that?

Thanks,

Comment: How does the `id_manufacturer` relate to the `description` and `short_description`? The data doesn't appear to be linked in any way in your question.

Comment: All tables are in the same database except noted.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I suspect you want logic like this.

```
INSERT INTO ps_manufacturer_lang (id_manufacturer, id_lang, description, short_description)
    SELECT m.id_manufacturer, 1, cl.description, NULL
    FROM ps_manufacturer m join
         prestashop_old.ps_category_lang  cl
         ON cl.id_lang = 1 and
            cl.id_category IN (
                SELECT id_category
                FROM prestashop_old.ps_category
                WHERE id_parent = 241
               );
```

Test the `select` first to see if it returns what you want.

Comment: @NimaMasalegooha . . . This is using the logic from your query to get that.

Comment: I just want to fill four columns in one table from four different columns in two tables.