# Adding different rows from different tables into another table using INSERT INTO and SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**EDIT 2:**
Original post caused more confusion over problem-solving, so I decided to explain the whole situation in details.

Let me clarify the whole situation...

I am working on an eCommerce CMS (Prestashop). Site owners mistakenly added all manufacturers (id, name, description) as categories.

I want to create proper structure for manufacturers table so we can correct this issue.

Let me explain the whole structure of `ps_manufacturer_lang` table which needs to be filled (it does not have any value in it).

**Table `ps_manufacturer_lang` has four `columns` named:**

1. `id_manufacturer`

2. `id_lang`

3. `description`

4. `short_description`

**Here are the values that should be inserted:**

1. `id_manufacturer` should be filled with values from `ps_manufacturer` table.

2. `id_lang` should be `1`.

3. `description` should be filled with values from `ps_category_lang` table with specific `WHERE` clause.

4. `short_description` should be `NULL`.

**Let's go to the queries:**

1. This `INSERT INTO` query fills `id_manufacturer` and `id_lang` properly:
`INSERT INTO ps_manufacturer_lang (id_manufacturer, id_lang)
SELECT
    id_manufacturer,
    1
FROM ps_manufacturer`

 2. This `INSERT INTO` query fills description properly:
`INSERT INTO ps_manufacturer_lang (description)
SELECT
    description
FROM ps_category_lang
WHERE
    id_lang='1'
    AND id_category IN (
        SELECT id_category FROM ps_category WHERE id_parent='241'
    )`

 Now, the question is, how to do this? It is not possible two use **ONE** `INSERT INTO` query with **TWO** `SELECT FROM` syntaxes.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be more specific about what you want to do ?

Comment: show us your insert into query code  ..

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense, an empty table has no rows.

Comment: Check my edit, guys.

Comment: Your second insert should be an update , please add your table definitions that way we can see the primary key (i suspect on id_manufacturer but just now only you know)

Comment: Isn't possible to use only 1 query to INSERT with two SELECT FROM?

Comment: share  `show create table table_name`

Comment: I edited the whole question to clarify everything...

Comment: Did your last query is working ?

Comment: SELECT description FROM ps_category_lang WHERE id_lang='1' AND id_category IN ( SELECT id_category FROM ps_category WHERE id_parent='241')

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly as I want.

Comment: I just don't know how to add two SELECT FROM queries inside one INSERT INTO

Comment: Same problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721054

Answer (score 0):

You have to use insert select statement to copy other tables data.

```
INSERT INTO ps_manufacturer_lang (description)
SELECT description
FROM ps_category_lang 
"your specific where condition"
```

To avoid duplicate entry , you have to make primary key **AUTO_INCREMENT**  or create trigger for this table

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists ps_manufacturer_lang,ps_manufacturer,ps_category_lang;

create table ps_manufacturer_lang
(id_manufacturer int primary key,
id_lang int,
description varchar(20),
short_description   varchar(20));

create table ps_manufacturer
(id int);

create table ps_category_lang
(id int, description varchar(20), id_parent int);

insert into ps_manufacturer values (1),(2);
insert into ps_category_lang values
(1,'aaa',241),
(2,'bbb',241);

insert into ps_manufacturer_lang 
select pm.id,1,pl.description,null
from   ps_manufacturer pm
join   ps_category_lang pl on pl.id = 1 and id_parent = 241;

select * from ps_manufacturer_lang;

+-----------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
| id_manufacturer | id_lang | description | short_description |
+-----------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
|               1 |       1 | aaa         | NULL              |
|               2 |       1 | aaa         | NULL              |
+-----------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks but you didn't get the question properly. :)

I will post the solution if I find.

Comment: Perhaps you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make your question answerable.

Comment: My question is answerable.
You didn't read carefully.
If I drop ps_category_lang, so from what table should I get description values? :)

3. description should be filled with values from ps_category_lang table with specific WHERE clause.

Comment: If it was you would have answers by now especially since this is the second question on this topic. It's impossible to quess what your existing code is doing because you have not provided table definitions - so in your second insert its not possible to say where columns are coming from and you have provided code which doesn't work from which we have to reverse engineer your intent.